# PHP, How to add php code inside redirect_uri?

Tags: php, facebook

i have a facebook code:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration.php?
         client_id=138987726427834&
         redirect_uri=https://xxx.com/login.php?login=<?php echo  $login; ?>&pass=<?php echo  $pass; ?>&
         fields=<?php echo urlencode($fields);?>"
</iframe>
```

i was wondering why the `$login` and `$pass` dont work inside the `redirect_uri`?
they don't render inside the link.

i see that the `ields=<?php echo urlencode($fields);?>"` takes php.

any idea?

thanks

Comment: Umm why are you passing `login` and `pass` in a clear string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to escape that parameter with

```
redirect_uri=<?php echo urlencode("https://xxx.com/login.php?login={$login}&pass={$pass}"); ?>&
```

If you don't URL encode the URL, then you will send the parameters `login` and `pass` to `registration.php`, not to `login.php`.

Also, passing sensitive data such as passwords directly as GET variables is a bad practice. You might at least encrypt the password if you have to send it via GET.